# x86 assembly (AT&T) write long to .dat file

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, x86, ascii, att

EDIT: I think writing it to the file is working fine, I don't think the exercise wanted me to actually be able to see the number.

I'm trying to write a buffer, which contains some strings and longs, to a .dat file. The strings are coming out fine but the longs come out as their ascii versions (as characters). 
This code, taken from Programming from the Ground Up, is 32-bit and being compiled on 64-bit Ubuntu with `as --32` and `ld -melf_i386`, which has not given me problems with other examples (or with this one other than the problem described here).

Specifically, in the following code I load the number 45 into a record that will be written to a .dat file:

```
record1: 
.ascii "Fredrick\0"             # converts string into byte data
.rept 31                        # padding to 40 bytes 
.byte 0                         # inserts a 0 at the end of the field
.endr

.ascii "Bartlett\0"             # converts string into byte data
.rept 31                        # padding to 40 bytes
.byte 0                         # inserts a 0 at the end of the field
.endr

.ascii "4242 S Prairie\nTulsa, OK 55555\0"  # converts string into byte data
.rept 209                                   # padding to 240 bytes
.byte 0                                     # inserts a 0 at the end of the field
.endr

.long 45                                    # age of this contact = 45
                                            # long is already 4 bytes
```

The whole record then eventually gets passed to the function `write_record`:

```
pushl ST_FILE_DESCRIPTOR(%ebp)
pushl $record1
call write_record
addl $8, %esp
```

The function `write_record` is this:

```
write_record:
pushl %ebp          # save old base pointer
movl %esp, %ebp     # make stack pointer the base pointer

pushl %ebx
movl $SYS_WRITE, %eax
movl ST_FILEDES(%ebp), %ebx
movl ST_WRITE_BUFFER(%ebp), %ecx
movl $RECORD_SIZE, %edx
int $LINUX_SYSCALL      # execute system call,
                        # sys_write returns # bytes written in %eax
                        # which is returned to the calling program

popl %ebx               

movl %ebp, %esp     # restore stack pointer 
popl %ebp           # restore base pointer
ret
```

The name and address come out fine but the 45 comes out as a hyphen (-). In other records, the number 29 comes out as a space and 36 as a $.

Both the .dat file, when opened with gedit, and the terminal [show these values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGPnW.png).

How can I print the actual values 45, 29, 36...?

Should this code be writing the ascii characters to the .dat file or should it be writing the numbers?

If it's writing the wrong thing to the file, how can I get it to write longs to the file and not characters? The code provided by the book is supposed to work correctly out of the box, at least in a 32-bit environment. Could this be a 32 vs 64-bit issue?

If it's writing to the file correctly, my issue is in my read function and a conversion would be needed there, no? Before I try to do some conversion that I've read about (divide by 10 and use the quotient and remainders in some way), I wanted to pinpoint where the issue was first.

Comment: If you want the number as text, just store them as text. I am sure the numbers in the address are printed correctly. If you insist on binary you need to convert to text at runtime. Note that numbers in text form tend to be of varying size, so you need padding there too if you want fixed size records.

Comment: @Jester I thought about storing the longs just like I do with the addresses but later on in this exercise I'll have to add 1 to each age (each long) and I didn't think I could if they were just text. Also, because the code provided by the book is not supposed to be altered and should work out-of-the-box so I'm assuming the issue lies in something I've done, or how I'm compiling the code, or something like that.

Comment: The `.long` stores numbers in binary. If you want to see that as text in your file, you need to convert yourself. It's not a compilation issue. Are you sure you need it as text in the file?

Comment: @Jester Oh ok, not sure if the author intends for me to be able to see these numbers visually now that I think about it. He might be expecting me to just take his word for it. In a following program, I am able to increment this long by 1, although the modified value still shows up as a character, but this is good enough for this exercise. Thanks